# Find all $x$ values such that the tangent line to the given curve satisfy a specific property

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

> Find all $x$ values such that the tangent line to the given curve satisfy a specific property.
>
> (a) $y=\frac{x²+1}{x+2}$; horizontal. (Answer = $-2
> +\sqrt3$)
>
> (b)$y=\frac{x²+1}{x+1}$; parallel to $y=x$. (Answer = none)

The tangent problem is confusing me a bit. Could anybody walk me through the steps I need to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The stated answer for the first question is incorrect.  The function has two horizontal tangents, at $x = -2 \pm \sqrt{5}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) you want the line to be horizontal means parallel to the x-axis means the slope should be 0 thus 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
you have $$y=\frac{x²+1}{x+2}$$
thus $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x(x+2)-(x^2+1)}{(x+2)^2}=\frac{(x^2+4x-1)}{(x+2)^2}$$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ gives $x^2+4x-1=0$
solve for x

b) in the second part you want the line to be parallel of $y=x$ thus the slope must be 1 thus 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$
$$\frac{(x^2+4x-1)}{(x+2)^2}=1$$
$$x^2+4x-1=x^2+4x+4$$
$$-1=4$$ 
which is not true thus you can not draw a tangent to the given curve y that is parallel to $y=x$

Comment: I got it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For a) $$f'(x)=\frac{x^2+2x-1}{(1+x)^2}$$ so it must be $$f'(x)=0$$
For b) such Tangent line must have the form

$y=x+n$
so solve the equation $$x+n=\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}$$ and set the discriminante equal to Zero.

Comment: I first tried your suggested approach for (b). I multiplied both sides of the equation by $(x+1)$ and ended up with $nx+x+n=1$. Since this is not a quadratic equation, there is no sense in setting the discriminant to zero. What am I missing?

Comment: note that you will have $$(x+n)(x+1)=x^2+1$$ this is quadratic, isn't it?

Comment: you will get $$x(n+1)=0$$ so we get $$n=-1$$

Comment: $$x²+x+nx+n=x²+1$$ Does $x²$ not cancel out?

Comment: Yes the $x^2$ will cancel out.